# How to make a batch file read the text of a .txt file

Tags: batch-file, windows-8, windows-7

I am trying to get a batch script to read the text from a document called "Response.txt". I can't seem to get it to read the text inside the file. The file says Yes. I want it to create a new text file to say week A if "Reponse.txt" = Yes.

```
@echo off 
IF Response.txt = Yes 
goto next 
:next 
ECHO >Week.txt 
ECHO Week >Week A.txt
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to this sort of thing so I am not even sure if this is close to correct :
@echo off
IF Response.txt = Yes goto next
:next
ECHO >Week.txt 
ECHO Week >Week A.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 
for /f %%a in (Response.txt) do if /i "%%a"=="Yes" ECHO Week >"Week A.txt"
```

Will create "Week A.txt" if any line in `response.txt` has a first word "Yes" in any case.

Beyond that, you'll have to explain further what you want to do.